# laravel download a newly created xmlfile

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-4, simplexml

I am trying to create xmlfile and download it from my program but it isnt working very well.

This is my code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydoc></mydoc>');

    $xml->addAttribute('version', '1.0');
    $xml->addChild('datetime', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $person = $xml->addChild('person');
    $person->addChild('firstname', 'Someone');
    $person->addChild('secondname', 'Something');
    $person->addChild('telephone', '123456789');
    $person->addChild('email', 'me@something.com');

    $address = $person->addchild('address');
    $address->addchild('homeaddress', 'Andersgatan 2, 432 10 Göteborg');
    $address->addChild('workaddress', 'Andersgatan 3, 432 10 Göteborg');

    $xml->saveXML('test.xml');

    $response = Response::make($xml->asXML(), 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    return $response;
```

This is showing the xmlfile in my browser, but i want a popup to appear, asking me to download the file i just created. I tried it with Response::download() to but that isnt working neither because the first parameter should be the path to the file then.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might need to add some more headers:

```
$response->header('Cache-Control', 'public');
$response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.xml');
$response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
$response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```